# SharePoint choice or lookup field representing other list's fields

Tags: sharepoint, data-structures

The scenario is that I have a Projects list and there are a bunch of different `SPFieldUser` fields associated to it. I have another list representing the Project's Logbook (it contains a bunch of data about different milestones of the project). The relationship is like this: (1 project list item : 1 logbook list).

I have to store some metadata in a logbook's list item that points to a specific user, stored in Project's list item. For that I have to create a choice field which represents different `SPFieldUser` fields from the project's list.

The question is which is optimal way of representing such a structure?

I can just hard-code a choice option for every `SPFieldUser` in a Projects list, but then when I have to reference this data in a code, I'll have to somehow transform the choice's value into internal name of the associated project's field.

I can also create a lookup of those fields and this way, accessing it is easy. I can show the Title to user and have the internal name stored in a lookup.

I was also thinking about defining some kind of custom `FieldType`, but I feel like it would require far more work than an of the other methods.

So which method do I choose? Can someone probably suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets check out your options one by one in terms of efforts and scalability.

1 Hardconding option : High efforts [Not at all recommended]
 - Column needs to be updated when new user joins or user leaves the
   company.
- Once format of data is specified its difficult to change. [e.g. FirstName+Lastname or Empid]

2. Highly recommended OOTB option : very low efforts

   - Configurable [Please check if you can change format of user data once added as lookup column.]
3. Custom column type will take coding efforts.

My recommendation is 2nd OOTB option. If you find some flaws in 2nd option let us know we can look for soultion.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the first option, as I was not going to hardcode usernames into the options, but fields of the list item. (e.g. Project list has manager and sponsor fields (which could be different users), so my options field would include these two options (Manager or Sponsor). I would have to update the field only if I were to add new user field to Project.